# webBrowser not loading sites

Tags: c#, web, browser

Hey would love to ask you guys what can be the problem if web browser in Windows Form app is not opening sites other then google. Tried multiple using www. http:// etc. but nothing really worked (didn't expect the problem to be there) as other thing which came to my mind is that the problem is on my web i tried different sites and even only php site with one html file which didn't load either anyone experienced this?

```
 private void Deposit10_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate("http://martindichtler.com/");
        Form1 logg = new Form1();
        string loggeduser = logg.loggeduser;

    }
```

Edit: There is button on other form which is opening up new form which contains browser

Comment: Nobody can hope to reliably answer this question with the information you've provided. Please show the code you're using to access these sites and list the error(s) you're receiving.

Comment: i'm not using any code for the sites even tho i tried. I list the site as default url which browser should load upon the form load but also did
 
 private void Deposit10_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate("http://martindichtler.com/");
            Form1 logg = new Form1();
            string loggeduser = logg.loggeduser;
            
        }

To test it out if it works this way, also there are no errors

Comment: Well Form_Load is code so show it. If you're not using code then this is off topic for a programming site. Edit the code into your question, not the comments.

Comment: done it, the code is there

Comment: This code doesn't show what the problem is at all. It just shows that you try to get `webBrowser1` to go to your website (which should work fine). The last two lines make no sense, you create a new form but don't show it, then try to get a value from it even though it can't exist. Are you sure that `webBrowser1` is definitely a control that you've added to your form and that it definitely pays attention to this event handler?

Comment: yes i'm, also the control you say makes no sense is getting data from main form, the program is over 3k lines now i doubt i could paste it here or you would find anything useful inside. It's used to save user name for currently logged user so i can see if he makes the payment or not which is the use of the browser.

Comment: "the problem is on my web i tried different sites and even only php site with one html file which didn't load either anyone experienced this" Please re-phrase this. I can't understand this at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in default browser, used CefSharp and Chromium and works fine